# Adding an Object to an NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays

Tags: objective-c

This is more of a theory question.  I have a NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays and I have one of my NSMutableArrays only adding one object to it so I feel that there isn't a need to have it in an array if its just one item.  However I thought that if you have an array of arrays you are only allowed to add an array to it.  Is this wrong?

Comment: You can add an NSArray, a NSDictionary, an NSNumber, an NSString, etc. to the same array if you wish. Just be careful when taking them out and doing something with them. But it sounds like a premature optimization to safe the overhead an array creates, putting only arrays in the array will make the code more readable, understandable and while reduce the potential for bugs.

Comment: You can, but as @luk2302 says it sounds dangerous, especially considering your main object is a NSMutableArray. Sounds like an easy way to introduce bugs